# Open all toggles at once

Tags: jquery, toggle

I use a toggles with the following code that also replaces the icons. When I start the page all toggles are closed. But for a print out I need all toggle open. Therefore I'd like to have a button to open all toggles at once.
I don't know much enough to get the piece of code together to open all toggles and get those icons right as well

here's the toggle code I use and the button code I want to use

```
     $(function(){
        var iconOpen = 'icon-minus',
            iconClose = 'icon-plus';

        $(document).on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', '.accordion', function (e) {
            var $target = $(e.target)
              $target.siblings('.accordion-heading')
              .find('em').toggleClass(iconOpen + ' ' + iconClose);
              if(e.type == 'show')
                  $target.prev('.accordion-heading').find('.accordion-toggle').addClass('active');
              if(e.type == 'hide')
                  $(this).find('.accordion-toggle').not($target).removeClass('active');
        });
    });


<button id="open_all">Open all</button>
```

How would the  jQuery code look like to open all?

Thanks for some help.

Here's the [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wernergusset/jRwnk/)  the icons are not in there

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of what exactly you want to do? As long as I can understand your question, following code should work on button click:

$(".collapse").addClass("in");

Comment: Yes Gaurav, this is what I was looking for. It's working in the fiddle.